# Invert colors of a WPF Image

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

I've been searching everywhere, can't find any answer.

How could I invert the colors of a BitmapSource or an Image (System.Windows.Controls.Image)
from WPF.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

you should use  [WPF Shader Effects Library](http://www.codeplex.com/fx)

it has a "negative" effect sample